# Which variable to set for programmatically making a field required?

Tags: entities, updating

I am trying to do something like :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function module_name_update_7002() {
 // Change field to required
}
```

To alter a field to make it required in production (where i can't access the backoffice).

Which variable do I have to set for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use following code to update your field

```
// Fetch an instance info array.
$instance_info = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
// Change a single property in the instance definition.
$instance_info['required'] = TRUE;
// Write the changed definition back.
field_update_instance($instance_info);
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the `form_id` of that form and write an alter function for it in your custom module.

```
function hook_form_form_id_alter() {
 $form['that_field_name'] = array(
   '#required' => TRUE,
    // add other features you want to add
 );
}
```

Follow the below link for more details:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7

Comment: But for the form ID to be called, you have to visit the page. I need it to be change when running a update.

Comment: You want to update a form field to a required field, right?
Then, in that case without using form_id, how can you make the changes?
Is this the same case you posted about?

Comment: I think that the way you described it works fine for me. But I don't want to write a code that will be launched each time If there is a way to write a function inside a hook_update_N(). Your answer works fine and if There are no other choice I'll end up doing it. It's just that the site that I am working on is already slowing and I am trying not to charge it more.